# implementing riemann sum for the area of a circle

Tags: c++

The following code is designed to implement this formula:

[image: area=∑_(i=1)^n = w*√(r^2-(w×(i-1/2))^2 )]

```
void integrate ( double R , double E )          //radius and acceptable error, entered by user
{
    int i = 1;                          //iterator
    int n = 1;                          //number of rectangles
    double x = 0;
    double width = 0;                   //stores width of each rectangle
    double area = 0;                    //stores calculated area
    double error = E + 1;               //stores difference between calculated area and pi*(radius)^2

    while ( error > E )                 //loop continues as long as error is greater than the acceptable limit entered by user
    {
        width = R / n;                  //sets the width of rectangles
        area = 0;                       //with this line, calculated area converges to zero. without it, calculated area increases without bound
        while ( i <= n )
        {
            x = i;                      //assign iterator value to a separate variable to avoid data type issues in calculation
            area += width * sqrt ( pow ( R , 2.0 ) - pow ( width * ( x - 0.5 ) , 2.0 ) );       //riemann integral formula
            i++;
        }
        n++;                                                    //increase number of rectangles by 1 to be used in next loop
        area *= 4;                                              //forumla uses one quarter of a circle, multiply by 4 to get total area
        error = abs ( area - ( pi * pow ( R , 2.0 ) ) );        //error calculation
        cout << " \n Calculated area = " << area << "\n"        //debugging output
             << " \n Error = " << error << "\n";
             cin.get();
    }
    cout << "\n Area: " << area << "\n"                         //output to user
         << "\n Error: " << error << "\n"
         << "\n Iterations: " << i << "\n";

    return;
}
```

As the comment says, when the line "area = 0;" is included in the first loop, the area converges to zero, and when it is removed, the area increases without bound. I've been working on this one function for the better part of a week without progress. The rest of the program is completed, tested, and works fine. I have to assume that there's either an error in the logic or the math that I just can't see. Any help would be appreciated.

I hope that the comments are sufficient. I'll provided additional clarification as necessary.

(This is a self-contained function. No other part of the program affects it or is affected by it aside from the user input.)

Comment: A number of your variables aren't being reset if your error is too high. `n` for example.

Comment: This is correct behavior. Each time the loop completes, it compares the calculated area to the expected area. If the resulting area is too great, the calculation is repeated, using 1 additional rectangle (n++)

However, I just realized that i is never reset, and I'm pretty sure it should be. I'll see if that change has any effect.

Comment: And that fixed it. It's always the simplest details that I miss. Thanks!